# Deleted 18.04 server. How to reinstall 18.04 server without loosing existing files?

Tags: server, system-installation, 18.04, lvm, boot-repair

Please excuse the way I've gotten into this situation. After upgrade from 16.04 LTS server to 18.04 LTS server I was removing 16.04 programs php7.2 depended on. One of those was SSL-something. Since I removed it, the whole server seems to be gone:

[image: Volume group vg not found]

[image: Alert! /dev/mapper --vg-root does not exist]

I've tried to boot from USB with iso of 18.04 server, but it only wants to format partitions before installation. When I've booted from USB with 18.04 desktop, I've run boot-repair to produce [this report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QYDNTQnqnV/).

Since the cause of failure is missing kernel, not corrupt boot records, I didn't proceed with boot-repair, partially because it'd replace grub 18.04 with 17.01.

So how can I install 18.04 server onto existing partitions and folders?

Answer (score 1):

I did as suggested: bought a new disk, added it to the computer and installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 on it. lvscan showed that old lvm volumes were active so I only had to mount them to gain access to my old files. In order to make mount persist between reboots I copied mounting instructions for LVM from my old /etc/fstab to the new one. Too late in the process I have come across [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition), which has a very interesting comment made by Timothy Martin. He says:

> You may be able to repair your installation by reversing your apt-get remove command. Have a look in /var/log/apt/history.log. You should be able to reinstall each of the packages that were removed.

All I had to do to try that was boot with Ubuntu 18.04 server USB, press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to switch to terminal and [chroot](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/recovering-from-unbootable-ubuntu-encrypted-lvm-root-partition/). The last command recorded in the /var/log/apt/history.log file that crippled my server was: apt-get remove --purge libssl*.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: at some point we all will learn to avoid mucking with libssl until we master its magic

Answer (score 0):

Tough situation.   Been there.
I would stop and not try to do anything else with that drive.

If your goal is to save critical files then putting the drive into another linux machine (or adding a new 2nd drive to the existing machine) is one easy way to get the files off.  Usually the file system is intact....just the boot partition is damaged or critical files are missing but otherwise the file system is often intact  and readable.

so I would temporarily remove the original drive.  Install a new drive then install 18.04 on that drive.  then shut down and install the old drive.  I will boot to the new drive and most likely mount the old drive as a readable 2nd drive.   Then you can copy the files back onto the new drive using the appropriate cp commands.

But if you goal is to recover this server, that gets more complicated.